# C# Struggling to read excel data into arrays (interop)

Tags: c#

First off I apologize I have asked this before but I never got an answer for it due to posting at quiet time of day.

I'm trying to read data from an xlsx document columns into array lists on a form based program so I can then call in various bits of data to manipulate or simply show onscren but can't get some code to work. I searched the forums and found this which according to the poster works but I'm having problems. I'm literally stuck on the matter as I've never had to write any code that involved excel.

The errors it throws are the words "Server, Missing & session" do not exist in the current context. I'm aware session isn't part of the winforms applications but dont know what to do about it.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

This is the main code

```
string filePath = "SampleData.xlsx";

try
{
   Excel.Application appExl;
   Excel.Workbook workbook;
   Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
   Excel.Range ShtRange;
   appExl = new Excel.Application();
   workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
   workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath(filePath), Missing.Value,         Missing.Value,
   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
   Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
   NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

   int Cnum = 0;
   int Rnum = 0;

   ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   for (int row = 1; row <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; row++)
   {
      string str = Convert.ToString((ShtRange.Cells[row, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2);
      dt.Columns.Add(str);
   }

   workbook.Close(true);
   appExl.Quit();

   Session["data"] = dt;

   return true;
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
   return false;
}
```

Is this a better representation of what it should be like?

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 using System.Reflection;

 string FilePath = "SampleData.xlsx";

    Excel.Application appExl;
    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    Excel.Worksheet NwSheet;
    Excel.Range ShtRange;
    appExl = new Excel.Application();
    workbook = appExl.Workbooks.Open(FilePath);

    NwSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets.get_Item(1);

    int Cnum = 0;
    int Rnum = 0;

    ShtRange = NwSheet.UsedRange;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    for (int row = 1; row <= ShtRange.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
       string str = Convert.ToString((ShtRange.Cells[row, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2);
       dt.Columns.Add(str);
    }

    workbook.Close(true);
    appExl.Quit();
```

Comment: `Server, Missing & session" do not exist in the current context`? Then those variables -- if they exist at all -- are declared outside of the scope of whatever you're doing here. [Please read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx). You need to show us more code -- what is this code contained in? Where are those 3 variables declared?

Comment: The duplicate was my post. At this moment in time what I posted is the only code I have in the program. Someone gave me it and said it was perfectly working for them as is.

Comment: I basically know nothing about reading and manipulating excel using c# so for all i know code may be useless

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to add the following references to your project:

```
System.Web
System.Reflection
```

You may also need to add the following to your code:

```
Using System.Web
Using System.Reflection
```

If this is a Winforms application, you won't need the System.web reference and you'll need to replace 'Server.MapPath(filePath)' with a filepath  Instead of 'Session["data"]' you will probably want to use a DataGrid.

Also looks like you are trying to open the file twice in succession.  Not sure why.

Comment: I have posted an edit in original post is this closer to the mark